# Display Validation messages as formcontrol changes

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-changedetection

Steps:

1. Go to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/04WLl9ofrQBlP7zisxP4?p=preview)
2. Go to `Name` input box
3. Leave `Name` empty
4. Go to `Email` & Type
5. As one types, required field error pops up for `Name`
6. I want this error to pop up as one moves from `Name` to `Email`, not after typing in `Email`

How I can do it?

Comment: `this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe`?

Comment: No. Still same behavior :(

Comment: To me it's unclear what the question is about. Why do you think `valueChanges` is related to validation errors?

Comment: I'm following  the example given  [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#reactive) . In `ngOnInit()` I have `buildform()` method and I am subscribing to form changes via `valueChanges` or `statusChanges`.
Now my validation logic and logic for error messages is inside that `onValueChanged` method. Validation is working fine, but it's not getting triggered as it is expected

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I go from first input control to second control without typing anything, ideally it should give 'required' error.

Why you are not using built in validators for required?
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html#built-in-validators

```
 <form novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="name" ngModel required>
  <input type="text" name="street" ngModel minlength="3">
  <input type="text" name="city" ngModel maxlength="10">
  <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel pattern="[A-Za-z]{5}">
</form>
```

Make use of validation mechanism from Angular.

Comment: I am using validation mechanism from Angular

Comment: `this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z .\\-]+$')])],
            contact: this.fb.group({
                mob: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{10}$')])],
                email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, EmailValidator.isValidMailFormat])]
            })
        });`

Comment: Difference in your form and mine is that I'm using model-driven forms

Comment: It does not matter. If you have Required validator it will give you errors on control. 
"You've said that Now my validation logic and logic for error messages is inside that onValueChanged method"
So maybe you just clear your errors somewhere in this logic. Can you provide a plunker with your example?